# How to open PDF file from internal storage in Oreo?

Tags: android, android-8.0-oreo

I try to open PDF file in Oreo but it does not open. I don't get any error. What is the issue? PDF file does not open. Only black screen is shown. In logcat no errors show. What is wrong?

How Can I resolve this issue? I referred many links but did not get solution. I also tried many codes but no help.

My Code is:

```
   File file11 = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().
   getAbsolutePath(), 
   "AtmiyaImages/" + nameoffile1);
    Intent target = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
    target.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT>24){
        Uri uri=FileProvider.getUriForFile(AssignmentActivity.this,
        getPackageName()+".provider",file11);
        target.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_PERSISTABLE_URI_PERMISSION);
        target.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM,uri);
        target.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        target.setType("application/pdf");
        Intent intent=Intent.createChooser(target,"Open File");
        try
        {
        startActivity(intent);
        }
        catch(ActivityNotFoundException e)
        {
        Toast.makeText(AssignmentActivity.this,"No Apps 
       can performs This acttion",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
        }

        else
        {
        target.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
        target.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(file11),"application/pdf");
        target.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY);
        Intent intent=Intent.createChooser(target,"Open File");
        try
        {
        startActivity(intent);
        }
        catch(ActivityNotFoundException e)
        {
        Toast.makeText(AssignmentActivity.this,"No Apps can performs This 
        acttion",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

        }
```

In **Manifest** I also add

```
   <provider
        android:name="android.support.v4.content.FileProvider"
        android:authorities="com.infinity.infoway.atmiya.fileprovider"
        android:exported="false"
        android:grantUriPermissions="true">
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
                android:resource="@xml/provider_paths"/>
       </provider>
```

And My **Xml code** is:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<paths>
<external-path
 name="Phonestorage"
path="/storage/emulated/0/AtmiyaImages"/>
</paths>
```

Comment: there might be some logs you're missing . please attach full  log at the time you open pdf

Answer (score 4):

Replace your path value with "." - Look at below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<paths xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <external-path name="external_files" path="."/>
</paths>
```

Inside Manifest, "provider" code is like this, your one is also true.

```
<provider
            android:name="android.support.v4.content.FileProvider"
            android:authorities="${applicationId}.provider"
            android:exported="false"
            android:grantUriPermissions="true">
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
                android:resource="@xml/provider_paths" />
        </provider>
```

For access proper file path follow this code:

```
File  pdfFile = new File(getExternalFilesDir(GlobalUtils.AppFolder), fileName);
     Uri path = FileProvider.getUriForFile(this, BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID + ".provider", pdfFile);
                Log.e("create pdf uri path==>", "" + path);

                try {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                    intent.setDataAndType(path, "application/pdf");
                    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
                    startActivity(intent);
                    finish();
                } catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                            "There is no any PDF Viewer",
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    finish();
                }
```

Hope this will help you.

Answer (score 1):

Some tweaks to Bhoomika's answer worked for me

`xml/providers_path.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<paths xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <files-path name="files" path="."/>
</paths>
```

`AndroidManifest.xml`

```
<provider
         android:name="androidx.core.content.FileProvider"
         android:authorities="APPLICATION_ID.provider"
         android:exported="false"
         android:grantUriPermissions="true">
         <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
            android:resource="@xml/provider_paths"/>
</provider>
```

A Kotlin Extension function to open the PDF from an activity

```
fun Activity.openPdf(filename: String?) {
    val file =  File(filesDir, filename)

    if(file.exists()) {
        Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW).apply {
            setDataAndType(FileProvider.getUriForFile(this@openPdf, BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID + ".provider", file), "application/pdf")
            flags = Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP
            addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION)
            try {
                startActivity(this)
            } catch (e: Exception) {
                showErrorDialog(unable_to_open_doc)
            }
        }
    } else {
        showErrorDialog(file_doesnt_exist)
    }
}
```